# Best way to copy file server 2008 r2 contents to a new 2012 r2 server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, replication, synchronization, file-server

I am making a DR site over the cloud and want to upload all my file server contents in the fast and most suitable way. There are many options like;

1. XCopy
2. Robocopy
3. DFS Replication
4. Third party tools like BeyondCompare

I want to know whats the best way to upload 100s of GB data for the least time.
Also I want to keep all my files synced together. If the changes are made over the DR file server, they sync quickly with the local server, and if the changes are made in local server, they quickly sync to DR. DFS Replication sounds to do this but I have not much time to test each n every tool. Want to know the best practices for the activity I am going to do.

Maybe I can use two tools, first take a shadow copy or something and later enable file syncing. But guide me a better solution.

P.S. I got a Windows 2008 R2 server locally, and I want to use a 2012 r2 over the cloud.

Comment: Have you calculated first your upload vs data you need upload every day? First upload is always huge, so I don't think you need to consider it.

Comment: For the initial sync?  [Sneakernet.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneakernet)

Answer (score 2):

What do you want is a bidirectional, asynchronous replication/mirroring.

The best tool at hand under Win2008+ (without buying special hardware/software) is DFSR. It was designed precisely with that WAN-routed replication in mind.

Comment: you are suggesting me to use DFS Replication? I heard its quiet slow when it comes to syncing a file server from scratch but its good if we already got the folders and need to be synced?

Comment: Yes, DFSR is your best friend here. It's apparent slowness is only due to it trying to preserve WAN bandwidth. I think that DSFR can be configured to use most of the available bandwidth; anyway, you can also preseed your remote server via robocopy and then let DFSR handle the incremental sync.